# Why I can only launch linssid from terminal using sudo

Tags: applications

I installed linssid from appcenter and it wont launch. It only launchs from the terminal using sudo. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because an outaged version of linssid in appcenter (2.9 I guess). The way how to get Super User privileges in GUI has meanwhile probably changed (you will need administrative privileges to sniff network traffic).

You can download an updated version from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linssid/files/) and install the deb manually or add a ppa to your system and install via terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:wseverin/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linssid
```

Please consider [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for) (old but still relevant) question and answer when adding external repos to your system.

Comment: Thnks for answer but downloading the updated version didn't solve it. I tried to add a sudo command in the launcher but didn't work.